# What is the best way to add translation.json file to a React app running inside docke

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, configuration, rancher

I am working on a react web application, which may require multi language support. I am using [i18n-next](https://www.i18next.com/) which internally loads the required configuration file from specific directory based on the language selected by user.
[image]

The word or scentences that needs to be translated may increase based the screens that user going to add and also if use adds new folder, we will loading those languages into our application.

What is the best way (I mean Scallable, Easy to configure, platform provided...) to satisfy the requirement?

( :( All I can think of is mounting an external locales folder to the folder inside container.. Is that the only way.. or something else is there..)

Note: kubernetes and rancher is there to manage. Plase provide solution/suggestion around that.

Nandri.

Comment: I'd treat the translation files like any other part of your application: include them in your source tree, commit them to source control, and `COPY` them into the Docker image.  This wouldn't require any special handling in Kubernetes or anywhere else and doesn't have special scaling concerns.

Comment: I can commit the default translation to the source code.. But what if we want to provide instant support to a language in a production environment. We just created  a dynamic kube config map (by reacing a file strcutur in a config directory) and linked it to the specify target files inside containers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add the files from the Storage bucket to Ci/CD & add files to the docker image and manage inside it that would be one way.

Following this way might be helpful during scaling up the application and need to manage the external locales folder and anything worried.

By external local folder mean you want to use the Host path of the node what if your node is changing by Kubernetes during maintenance how will you add the files to the node each time or manage it?

If you will use the PVC you might face the issue of **readwriteonce** if you are scaling the replicas you require the **readwritemany**. Make try to create stateless containers as much as possible.

If you can create and add the directory inside the docker image and directly use it that would be perfect or else you might could use the NFS like [minio](https://min.io/) or [glusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/) which support the **readwritemany** also.